# Strange T_Variable error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, syntax

I am trying to write a PHP script to auto-post to WordPress some data from my database.

I keep getting a T_VARIABLE error but can't work out what I am doing wrong.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in c/public_html/example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/exampletemplatefile.php on line 50
```

Line 50 is

```
$linkid = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

And the rest of the script is:

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: example template file 3
    */
    ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE wp_posted='0' LIMIT 1");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {             
         $IDID = $row['ID'];
        $stats_ID = $row['stats_ID'];
        $Date = $row['Date'];
        $Competition_ID = $row['Competition_ID'];
        $Competition = $row['Competition'];
        $compgroup = $row['compgroup'];
        $Home_ID = $row['Home_ID'];
        $Home = $row['Home'];
        $Homeshort = $row['Homeshort'];
        $HomePath = $row['HomePath'];
        $Away_ID = $row['Away_ID'];
        $Away = $row['Away'];
        $AwayShort = $row['AwayShort'];
        $AwayPath = $row['AwayPath'];
        $Status = $row['Status'];
        $wp_posted = $row['wp_posted'];
        $wp_url = $row['wp_url'];
        $wp_post_id = $row['wp_post_id'];
    }



    $title = "hi"; 

    $description = "des hi";

    $ccat1 = "1";

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => "$title",
      'post_content'  => "$description",
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => "$ccat2"

    )

    $linkid = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );

    mysql_query("UPDATE events SET wp_post_id='$linkid'
    WHERE ID='$IDID' ");

    mysql_query("UPDATE events SET wp_posted='1'
    WHERE ID='$IDID' ");

    $permalink = get_permalink( $linkid ); 
    echo "Title: $title <br />";
    echo "Description: $description <br /><br />";

    ?>
```

The reason I say it is strange is that I have checked for missing brackets and taken away parts of the script to try and debug. If I remove `$linkid` and everything below it there is no errors just a blank WordPress page with the header. If I just remove parts of the code below `$linkid` I still get the same error albeit on different lines.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon the line before the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on the line before:

```
$my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => "$title",
      'post_content'  => "$description",
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => "$ccat2"

    )
```

should be

```
$my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => "$title",
      'post_content'  => "$description",
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => "$ccat2"

    );
```

Comment: Thanks. Silly me. Where I was tired I tried that before the bracket instead of after and then spent hours trying everything else. lol

Answer (score 1):

There is a semicolon missing at line number 48. Not sure if this is the solution but this might the problem.

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => "$title",
  'post_content'  => "$description",
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => "$ccat2"

) // <------- here semicolon is missing.

$linkid = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

Answer (score 0):

add semicolon

```
 $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => "$title",
      'post_content'  => "$description",
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => "$ccat2"

    ); // HERE
```